Nicola Tesla in Penny Dreadful?
My memory is probably combining two different shows, but I seem to remember watching an an episode of Penny Dreadful in 2014 where Vanessa and Malcolm take Ethan to some party to meet Jonathan Harker (Mina's hubby/ lover) and some mysterious guy who shows up at Malcolm's house trying to convince them to hire him. 
I fuzzily remember a ballroom scene in which an inventor gives a speech about the "new" concept of electricity, and has someone in the basement flip on the power and all of these prototype light-bulbs illuminate and astound the party guests. 
I think the guy was supposed to be Tesla or Edison, and then I remember the aforementioned Penny Dreadful characters following a mysterious guest home from the party. Please tell me what my brain is doing, because I think these things come from two different shows! I want to know the name of the movie or TV series that has the electric light bulb inventor's party. 
The reason I can't find out on my own is because I haven't finished season 1 of Penny Dreadful, and I don't want to run into spoilers searching for my answer. Please help!

Voted to undelete the Dracula answer posted here because I'm pretty sure it was correct and was about to post it myself, it just needs to be fleshed out a little. It was in the pilot.
